# Javascript - Make same function have different inputs

Tags: javascript, function

So in Java, you can do:

```
void F(int x, int y) {
  run(x, y);
}

void F(String a) {
  say(a);
}
```

but in Javascript you always have to do:

```
function F(x, y) {
  if (typeof x == "string") {
    say(a);
  } else {
    run(x, y)
  }
}
```

I want to do something like the Java functions in Javascript without checking every single thing, anyway to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the number of arguments using the `arguments` variable, like this:

```
function F(x, y) {
  if (arguments.length == 1) {
    say(x);
  } else if (arguments.length == 2) {
    run(x, y)
  }
}
```